# Excel Interop - Add a new worksheet after all of the others

Tags: c#, excel, interop

I am trying to add a new worksheet to an Excel workbook and make this the last worksheet in the book in C# Excel Interop.

It seems really simple, and I thought the below code would do it:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var excel = new Excel.Application();

            var workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\test\Test.xlsx");
            workbook.Sheets.Add(After: workbook.Sheets.Count);

            workbook.Save();
            workbook.Close();

            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excel);
        }
    }
}
```

No such luck. I get this helpful error:

> COMException was unhandled - Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC

I found [this page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/107622) on Microsoft.com which suggested I try and add the sheet first and then move it so I tried that as shown below. I know that this webpage targets Excel 95 but the VBA is still there to use so I was hoping it would still work:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var excel = new Excel.Application();

            var workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\test\Test.xlsx");
            workbook.Sheets.Add();
            workbook.Sheets.Move(After: workbook.Sheets.Count);

            workbook.Save();
            workbook.Close();

            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excel);
        }
    }
}
```

I get the same error as above. I have also tried passing the name of my last worksheet as a string as the `After` parameter in both the `Add` and `Move` methods, no joy!

That is what I have tried, so my question is how do I add a worksheet to an Excel workbook and make this the last sheet in the workbook using C# Excel Interop?

Thanks

Comment: JMK - not an answer to your issue but perhaps a helpful pointer for c# and excel. I've been using the LinqToExcel library for quite some time and really can't express how much cleaner an experience it is VS using interop methodology. If you have the time, take a look at it to see if it'll fit with your requirements. https://github.com/paulyoder/LinqToExcel also http://code.google.com/p/linqtoexcel/

Comment: @jimtollan Thankyou for the heads up, I will make a point of checking out LinqToExcel, it looks good. Thanks!

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Looking at the documentation here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.move(v=vs.80).aspx, it indicates that the 'after' object isn't a numerical position; it's the object representing the sheet you want to position your sheet after. The code should probably be something like (untested):

```
workbook.Sheets.Add(After: workbook.Sheets[workbook.Sheets.Count]);
```

Comment: This didn't work as a parameter for the `Move` method, but it did work as a parameter for the `Add` method! Thankyou very much!

Comment: It's tested now.  This makes a lot of sense.  Like you said, the new sheet isn't being inserted after a number, but rather after a sheet that is in that numbered position (base 1 for Excel).

Comment: I got a COMException on this on the Add() call if it is a XLSM file.

Comment: Flawless victory :D

Answer (score 8):

This should do the job:

```
wSheet.Move(Missing.Value, workbook.Sheets[workbook.Sheets.Count]);
```

Answer (score 5):

This is the only way that works for me:

```
xlWorkSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.Add
    (System.Reflection.Missing.Value,
     xlWorkBook.Worksheets[xlWorkBook.Worksheets.Count], 
     System.Reflection.Missing.Value, 
     System.Reflection.Missing.Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

it works for me

```
WorkBook.Worksheets.Add(
    System.Reflection.Missing.Value,
    WorkBook.Worksheets[WorkBook.Worksheets.Count], 
    1, 
    System.Reflection.Missing.Value);
```