# Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC While exporting Datagridveiw to excel

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview

Kindly help me with this issue.

```
if (dataGridViewAssets.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            copyAlltoClipboard();
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlexcel;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
            object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
            xlexcel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            xlexcel.Visible = true;
            xlWorkBook = xlexcel.Workbooks.Add(misValue); 
            xlWorkSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range CR = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1];
            CR.Select();
            xlWorkSheet.PasteSpecial(CR, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, true);
        }
```

I'm getting error

> Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC

from this line :`xlWorkBook = xlexcel.Workbooks.Add(misValue);`

Comment: What is the exception details? Stack trace would be nice.

Comment: Per this link, [Excel Interop - Add a new worksheet after all of the others](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12156302/excel-interop-add-a-new-worksheet-after-all-of-the-others),  "The error code 0x800A03EC means NAME_NOT_FOUND; in other words, you've asked for something, and Excel can't find it."  Q: Do you really need to use "System.Reflection.Missing.Value"?  Why not just declare an "Object", and add it?

Comment: Do you have MS Excel on webserver ?

Comment: I can' add the trace details here. Which line specifically you want? I would post that alone. Thanks

Comment: Yeah I have MS Excel in my machine.

Comment: How about `xlWorkBook = xlexcel.Workbooks.Add()` (no ""System.Reflection.Missing.Value")?

Comment: @paulsm4 I tried but same error.