# Adding a worksheet fails - only on .XLSM file

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop

I am trying to add a worksheet to a workbook and it works fine for a .XLSX file. But for a .XLSM file - I get the dreaded COMException 0x800A03EC.

I have tried all of the following and all fail:

```
wrkbk.Worksheets.Add(Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
wrkbk.Worksheets.Add(wrkbk.Worksheets[wrkbk.NativeWorkbook.Worksheets.Count], Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
wrkbk.Worksheets.Add(Type.Missing, wrkbk.Worksheets[wrkbk.NativeWorkbook.Worksheets.Count], Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
```

Questions [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12156302/excel-interop-add-a-new-worksheet-after-all-of-the-others), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/193092/c-sharp-how-to-add-an-excel-worksheet-programmatically-office-xp-2003?rq=1), & [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37858167/error-adding-a-new-sheet-to-a-xlsm-macro-excel-file) suggest the above, but it doesn't work, for me at least, with a .XLSM file.

Comment: can you do *anything* in that xlsm (thinking about modal security prompts or the dreaded "Enable content" bar)? which version and instantiation method of PIA do you use?

Comment: @dlatikay - I can read from and write to a cell from my AddIn. Is there something else I should check?

Comment: All xlsm files, or just individual one(s)? Have you tried on more than one system (computer)? Does it work via VBA in your environment, or does that also have problems with the Worksheets.Add method?

Comment: @CindyMeister Hi Cindy!!! Long time since we talked. It's just 1 .XLSM file. We're asking our customer if we can share it.

Comment: @CindyMeister - Your question led me to it - the workbook is locked. Therefore, no adding worksheets.

Comment: Glad you found the reason!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is failing because the workbook is locked. A locked workbook cannot have worksheets added to it.